# c# Subtract is not accurate even with decimals?

Tags: c#, math

I'm learning TDD and, decided to create a Calculator class to start.
i did the basic first, and now I'm on the Square Root function.

I'm using this method to get the root http://www.math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U1L9DP.html 
i tested it with few numbers, and I always get the accurate answers.
is pretty easy to understand.

Now I'm having a weird problem, because with some numbers, im getting the right answer, and with some, I don't.

I debugged the code, and found out that I'm not getting the right answer when I use subtract.

I'm using decimals to get the most accurate result.

when I do:

```
18 / 4.25
```

I am currently getting: `4.2352941176470588235294117647`

when it should be:  `4.2352941176470588235294117647059` (using windows calculator)

in the end of the road, this is the closest i get to the root of `18`:

```
4.2426406871192851464050688705 ^ 2 = 18.000000000000000000000022892
```

my question is:

Can i get more accurate then this?

Comment: This is how floating point arithmetic works: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: When you say "decimal", do you mean the `decimal` type? Or are you using `double` or `float`?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque i mean decimal type

Comment: Square roots of numbers that aren't perfect squares are irrational. You can't hope to store them accurately in a numeric format.

Comment: @harold so what is the answer to that problem? i mean, what if i create a bank account class? i got to have the most accurate number. what then?

Comment: You say "substract" (which is closest to "subtract"), but you appear to be performing division. And decimal is *defined* to have [28-29 significant digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx). It can't store more digits that that.

Comment: @samy there is no answer. You can get "more" accuracy, but never enough to accurately represent the square root of 18.

Comment: 18/4.25 is not irrational; it is rational, and the exact result is 4 4/17. If you want to work with this number without loosing precision you need a library that can perform computations with rational numbers. The square root is of course irrational and even harder to work with if you don't want to loose precision.

Comment: Maybe `18/4.25=4.235294117647058823529411764705882352941176470588235294117647058823529411764705882352941176470588235 :)
`

Comment: Try expressing 0.1 in binary and you'll understand why floating point numbers act the way they do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`4.2352941176470588235294117647` contains 29 digits.

[`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) is define to have 28-29 significant digits. You can't store a more accurate number in a `decimal`.

What field of engineering or science are you working in where the 30th and more digits are significant to the *accuracy* of the overall calculation?

(It would also, possibly, help if you'd shown some more actual code. The only code you've shown is `18 / 4.25`, which can't be an actual expression in your code, since the second number is a `double` literal, and you can't assign the result of this expression to a `decimal` without a cast).

---

If you need arbitrary precision, then there isn't a standard "BigRational" type, but there is a [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). You could use that to construct a `BigRational` type if you need that (storing numerator and denominator as two separate integers). One guess of why there isn't a standard type yet is that decisions on *when* to e.g. normalize such rationals may affect performance or equality comparisons.

Comment: well, i guess this is much more complex then i thoghot lol. thank u for the info. i didnt show any code, becuse i did some testing and it worked with diffrent numbers, like 17 and even 12.5. its still wierd for me that i cant do it, but now i know why. also, im kinda new to programming and i did this for fun :)

Answer (score 3):

Floating point calculations are not accurate. Decimals make the accuracy better, because they are 128-bit long, but they are still floating point numbers.

Comparing two floating point numbers is not done with `==`, but rather:

```
static bool SameDecimal(decimal a, decimal b)
{
    return Math.Abs(a-b) < 1e-10;
}
```

This method will allow you to compare two decimals (I assume 1e-10 is a small enough difference for you, it should be for everyday uses).

Comment: If you're going to do this, you should be looking at the ratio, not the difference of two values and compare the ratio to 1.  If the absolute difference of the ratio and 1 is within 1e-10 you might be onto something.  But, 1e-20 and 2e-20 will have an absolute difference of 1e-20, but by your metric, these two values are equal.

Comment: @andand It's no correct to always use one or the other.  They will each generate false positives/false negatives in certain situations.  You need to know what types of numbers you're likely to have to know which is likely to be more accurate.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough.  Can you provide an example where my approach yields a false positive or negative yet it would perform properly for the approach zmbq proposed?  I'm having some difficulty doing so.

Comment: @andand If your application logic says that all numbers of absolute value less than 1e-10 (or whatever) shall be considered 0, your approach would consider values different that it should consider equal that would be considered equal by the difference approach. Of course, the difference approach would still consider 8e-11 and 1.5e-10 equal although it probably shouldn't. Both approaches have the problem that "equality" is not transitive (even when no NaNs are involved). How to compare floating-point values is _very_ dependent on the situation, no rule fits all.