# Strange subtraction in c#

Tags: c#, math

I am doing a c# program.. I must do a simple mathematical operation.

```
72057594037927936.0 - 255.0 = .....
```

Both numbers are double... I obtain

```
72057594037927680.0
```

instead of

```
72057594037927681.0
```

Can anyone explain me please how is it possible?

Thanx

Comment: Can we have some kind of filter to detect floating point error questions?  this is literally the most common programming question ever but in a form like this it's a little hard to automatically detect.

Comment: Thanks to duffymo's comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653916/c-sharp-substract-is-not-accurate-even-with-decimals?rq=1), Goldberg's article  [docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is essential reading for floating point issues.

Comment: This question did not bother me. Maybe if I had been around longer answering questions, I would find it redundant. But it is very cleanly written. Title could use improving perhaps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The exact result of the subtraction,

```
72057594037927681 = 0xffffffffffff01
```

needs 56 bits of precision, but `double` has only 53, hence the result is rounded to the nearest representable number.

Comment: Congrats to you on 100K RP :)

Answer (score 6):

Because floating point numbers only have limited precision. Adding / subtracting a small number from a large number can result in round-off errors.

If you convert your code to use [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s instead (which are much more precise but have a smaller range), you'll get the answer you expect:

```
// using doubles
72057594037927936.0 - 255.0 // 72057594037927680.0

// using decimals
72057594037927936.0m - 255.0m // 72057594037927681.0m
```

Comment: Especially useful, since you mention decimals as an alternative. Kudos!